# Resin with Apache configuration (mod_caucho) on windows

Tags: apache2, resin

I have PC with Windows x32, Apache 2.2 and Resin 3.0.14 installed and I need to configure Apache with Resin. I already red the article http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/install/cse-apache.xtp, but still have troubles. 
Here is configuration from Apache

```
LoadModule mod_caucho "c:/Program Files/resin-3.0.14/win32/apache-2.0/mod_caucho.dll"
ResinConfigServer localhost 6802

<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName myapp.com
      ResinConfigServer localhost 6802
      DocumentRoot C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/myapp.com/webapps/ROOT
      DirectoryIndex default.htm index.jsp redirect.jsp index.html
      <Location /caucho-status>
         SetHandler caucho-status
      </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I restarting the Apache it shows the following

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 494 of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundati
on/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files/resin-3.0.14/win32/ap
ache-2.0/mod_caucho.dll into server: The specified module could not be found.
Note the errors or messages above, and press the <ESC> key to exit.
```

I took mod_caucho.dll for Apache 2.2 from Resin 4.0.32 and place it to my Resin folder, but in this case I receive another error

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 494 of C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundati
on/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Can't locate API module structure `mod_caucho' in
file C:/Program Files/resin-3.0.14/win32/apache-2.2/mod_caucho.dll: No error
Note the errors or messages above, and press the <ESC> key to exit.
```

Did anyone face with such problem? How to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Apache 2.2, you should be using Resin 3.1.x or Resin 4.0.x.

You can't mix mod_caucho.dll for different versions of Resin, because the protocol is tweaked from time to time.

Also, when you do install with Resin 3.1.x or Resin 4.0.x, since there's a win32 and win64 complication of the mod_caucho.dll, you'll need to use the appropriate one.